# How do I test the URL mapping for a grails web service

Tags: grails

I'd like to test the URL Mappings for a simple REST web service that I'm setting up in Grails. The problem is that the URL mappings are defined with the HTTP method:

```
class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {
        "/blah/$city/$date"(controller:"blah"){
            action = [GET:"show", PUT:"update", POST:"save"]
        }
    }
}
```

The GrailsUrlMappingsTestCase doesn't seem to support passing in an HTTP method, it just takes a URL and a list of assertions.

Is there a way to get the GrailsUrlMappingsTestCase to play nice with RESTful webservice mappings? Or, is there a different way or better to test URL mappings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original code has not this feature. I see two possibilities how to do test REST service.

### 1) Functional test

You can setup a functional test which tests your app on running web container. Your application will be deployed and functional test will run. The tests are Unit tests again.
Take a look on [grails functional testing](http://www.grails.org/Functional+Testing) or [functional testing plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/functional-test).

### 2) Extend GrailsUrlMappingsTestCase

Since grails is open source you can extend *GrailsUrlMappingsTestCase* and add this feature. The source code for this class [looks quite simple](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#xOoVUSR8ZWM/grails/src/groovy/grails/test/GrailsUrlMappingsTestCase.groovy&q=GrailsUrlMappingsTestCase&d=5).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I'm going to try to extend GrailsUrlMappingTestCase as soon as I get a chance. It is currently covered with functional tests.

Comment: And when you finish it commit it also into grails project.